# C++ uint64_t bitwise AND check for even number

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and, uint64

I have the following code that simply checks if a uint64_t is even, I intended on using a bitwise AND operation to check but it doesn't seem to be working.

This is the code I thought would work first:

```
int n;
scanf("%d",&n);
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    uint64_t s,d;
    scanf("%llu %llu",&s,&d);
    //try for x
    uint64_t x;
    bool stop = false;
    x = s + d;
    printf("%llu",x&1ULL); \\ This prints 0 when the number is even but
    if(x&1ULL==0ULL){ \\ This check always returns false
        printf("%llu",x);
        x/= 2;
```

This code always prints out 0 or 1 if the the number is odd or even but the if statement always returns false. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: If you're not certain of the operator precedence rules, put in the extra parentheses. Also if you are certain.

Comment: If this is C++, why not use `std::cin`? This is 100% C code.

Comment: @tadman Some like iostream, some hate it and some love-hate it. Nothing wrong with using the old apis.

Comment: You have an operator precedence issue.

Comment: @tadman in this case this program is for a programming competition so I use printf,scanf and bitwise operations as they are much faster, You are correct though, in general practice I would use cin

Comment: @AlanStokes If you're not certain of the operator precedence rules, look them up.

Comment: @EoinDavey Faster in what sense? How many billions of operations of this function are you doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`x&1ULL==0ULL` is equivalent to `x&(1ULL==0ULL)`. You need `(x&1ULL)==0ULL`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdint.h>



int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        uint16_t  s, d;
        scanf_s("%llu %llu", &s, &d);
        //try for x
        uint16_t x;
        bool stop = false;
        x = s + d;
        printf("%llu", x & 1ULL);
        if ((x & 1ULL) == 0ULL) {

            printf("%llu", x);

            x /= 2;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I think  this  should work  anyway  for me  it works